# html input type inside a php file

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

i have a table that display a record from the database. Using this php file i would like to display the table inside the php file. I know is something wrong with this line in my code but i don't know how to fix it. I am trying to use a checkbox here to delete a row in my database.

here is that line of code:

```
echo "<td>  <input name=\"need_delete[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]\" value=\"<? echo $rows['id']; ?>\">  </td>";
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What's the error? Can you post the HTML that comes from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's wrong is because you're attempting to use php code (the variables) in the middle of a string. You must first close the string and then display the variables:

```
echo "<td>  <input name=\"need_delete[".$rows['id']."]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[".$rows['id']."]\" value=\"".$rows['id']."\">  </td>";
```

Alternatively you can close the PHP code and make it interpret as HTML (I prefer this way):

```
?><td>  <input name="need_delete[<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">  </td>";<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<td><input name="need_delete['.$rows['id'].']" type="checkbox" id="checkbox['.$rows['id'].']" value="'.$rows['id'].'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the php processing directives each time you want to use a php variable within your code. If you are using 'echo', I assume you have already declared that this is php, so you can just write the variables as:

```
echo "<html attribute='".$var."'></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<td><input name='need_delete[".$rows['id']."]' type='checkbox' 
         id='checkbox[".$rows['id']."]' value='".$rows['id']."'>  </td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In addition if you use single quotes to wrap you html, you won't have to escape your double quotes.

```
echo '<td><input name="need_delete['.$rows['id'].']" type="checkbox" id="checkbox['.$rows['id'].']" value="'.$rows['id'].'"></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
echo '<td><input name="need_delete[' .$rows['id'] .']" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[' .$rows['id'] .']" value="' .$rows['id'] .'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo <<<html
    <td> 
         <input name="need_delete[{$rows['id']}]" 
         type="checkbox" id="checkbox[{$rows['id']}]" value="{$rows['id']}" />  
    </td>
html;
```

simple!